# Is there a more elegant way of arranging my forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a rather novice programmer who recently came up with a solution that works for my project, however I'm always looking for ways to improve my code.

So essentially, I have a settings form that pop's up and I was looking for a way to put it next to my main form but not covering it nor appearing partially off of the screen the main form is on.  I came up with this but it's not very *dynamic* because it only checks 4 different locations and if none of them work it uses the default, which is center screen.

Here is what I have:

```
private void Place_Form(Form formToPlaceNextTo, Form formToPlace)
    {
        Point alignRightTop = new Point(m_parent.Location.X + m_parent.Width, m_parent.Location.Y);
        Point alignRightBottom = new Point(m_parent.Location.X + m_parent.Width, (m_parent.Location.Y + m_parent.Height) - this.Height);
        Point alignLeftTop = new Point(m_parent.Location.X - this.Width, m_parent.Location.Y);
        Point alignLeftBottom = new Point(m_parent.Location.X - this.Width, (m_parent.Location.Y + m_parent.Height) - this.Height);

        if (Screen.FromControl(formToPlace).WorkingArea.Contains(new Rectangle(alignRightTop.X, alignRightTop.Y, this.Width, this.Height)))
        {
            this.Location = alignRightTop;
            return;
        }
        if (Screen.FromControl(formToPlace).WorkingArea.Contains(new Rectangle(alignRightBottom.X, alignRightBottom.Y, this.Width, this.Height)))
        {
            this.Location = alignRightBottom;
            return;
        }
        if (Screen.FromControl(formToPlace).WorkingArea.Contains(new Rectangle(alignLeftTop.X, alignLeftTop.Y, this.Width, this.Height)))
        {
            this.Location = alignLeftTop;
            return;
        }
        if (Screen.FromControl(formToPlace).WorkingArea.Contains(new Rectangle(alignLeftBottom.X, alignLeftBottom.Y, this.Width, this.Height)))
        {
            this.Location = alignLeftBottom;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions or *preferred* coding techniques?

Comment: The *preferred* technique is to let Windows position the window/form automatically. Attempting to monkey with it just increases the likelihood that you'll get it wrong.

Comment: If you have a code which works, but you'd like to improve it then probably http://codereview.stackexchange.com might be more appropriate here. SO is mostly for 'broken' code

Comment: @Snowbear Thank you, I had no idea that site existed.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Yes, I'm sure that's a preferred way but it defaults over the main form and this is a problem because the settings form changes the visuals of the main form.  The user can move the settings form to see the changes happen as they are changed on the settings form however, I'm trying to make it more user friendly.

Comment: So give them the ability to have it docked (how they like) or floating (where they like), and save their preferred setting. Anything else means you are going to irritate a significant %age of users no matter what you do.

Comment: Writing things yourself is not always the best options. You might want to use something ready made instead, like [DockPanel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/) in this case. Not exactly aligning forms, but a much smother experience.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo I have seen that before and it looks good.  However, the main app form is very small, about 200x100 - so I'm not coming even close to using the full screen.  The reason I'm using this code is to place the settings form next to but not covering the main form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Snowbear, I used another SE site to ask the same question and got a good response.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8881/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-of-arranging-my-forms